# Python script does not print output

Tags: python

I have this simple python program:

```
def GetNum (Text):
    x = input("Input something: ")
    while (x > 0):
        x = input("Input something: ")

    print x
```

And I want to run that through terminal, but when I do the command:

```
python ./test.py
```

or if I run

```
python test.py
```

Nothing happens. The terminal just goes back to normal, as if no command was ever executed.

The file is located under Documents/Python and I am in that directory when I am running the command. Am I missing something here as to why this is not working?

Comment: Assuming this is all of your code: You need to call your function `GetNum` and pass the argument `Text` to it when calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't called your `GetNum` function.

You need to add the following to the bottom of your script:

```
GetNum(None)
```

`Text` is not used, so None is a null object.

You may want to read up on defining functions, function arguments and calling functions, which is out-of-scope for StackOverflow - See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Answer (score 5):

Your program does not output anything because you are never calling your function.

This will do what you expect:

```
def GetNum():
    x = int(input("Input something: "))
    while (x > 0):
        x = int(input("Input something: "))

    print(x)

GetNum()
```

I removed the function argument `Text`, added a call to the `GetNum` function and added type conversions from `str` to `int` for both `input()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

make the code as such, no function

```
x = input("Input something: ")
while (x):
    x = input("Input something: ")

print x
```

Comment: You will have an infinite loop with this.

Comment: no, just hit enter without entering any text and you are good. just tried it

Comment: That is the exception. You would probably just want to convert the input into an `int` and have it do something, otherwise its meaningless.

Comment: i suppose it depends on the context

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways
But the easiest one is to call the function i.e GetNum (some text)